# Is it possible for a function to not have a second derivative?

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

So I am studying Newton's method and I realize the only two cases where it cannot achieve quadratic convergence is when the first derivative is 0 and second derivative does not exist.

However, how could second derivative not exist? as I thought a function is always dfferentiatable until it reaches $0$.  Do you have an example where a function cannot have a second derivative?

and also, zero first derivative means the $f'(x)$ of a function is zero at the root, then for example

$(x-2)^2=0$ --- where there is a multiple root and newton's method does not achieve quadratic convergence, but the first derivative is not 0 at root. Why?

Comment: Think of a function which isn't differentiable, then integrate it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function .

Comment: "a function is always dfferentiatable until it reaches $0$"  What does that mean?? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I'm guessing the OP mostly has experience with polynomials which do eventually differentiate to $0$.

Comment: When I read that, I thought of things like $y=x^2$, which is differentiable every where including the point at which it reaches $0$, i.e. $y$ reaches $0$ when $x=0$.

Comment: you could take a piecewise defined function $f(x)=0$ for $x\le0$, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\ge0$. Then $f'(x)=0$ for $x\le0$, $f'(x)=2x$ for $x\ge0$, and $f''(0)$ does not exist. But I did not attempt to see if and how this example might relate to Newton's method, perhaps it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continuous everywhere (for simplicity) and not differentiable at $x_0$, then $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y) dy$ is differentiable only once at $x_0$. For a concrete example, the function

$$F(x)=\int_{-1}^x |y| dy$$

is differentiable only once at $0$. Thus the Newton iteration for

$$G(x)=\int_{-1}^x |y| dy - \frac{1}{2}$$

for initial conditions close to zero, should not be expected to converge quadratically.

In your example you just have a calculation error, $\frac{d}{dx} (x-2)^2 = 2(x-2)$ which is indeed zero at $x=2$.

Comment: thanks. but is it fair to say that when a function has a turning point / point of inflection at its root, the function will not converge quadratically?   and the turning point is not at the root, but if the first guess is at its turning point, where tangent will not have a solution, Newton's method will not even work?

Comment: @gigi If $f'=0$ at the root then you will not have quadratic convergence. Higher derivatives being zero at the root makes the convergence still be linear, but slower. If the initial condition has $f'=0$ then you can't run Newton's method because you get forced to divide by zero.